# is it possible to search case insensitive search using command line [windows 7]

Tags: grep, find

I use

grep -f d.txt OB.txt > r.txt

to get the result file.

But the search is case sensitive. Is there any case insensitive alternative to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the switch `-i` with grep to specify case insensitive.